# SignUp form with NodeJs mongodb(mongoose) express using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I am having a signup form with fields like username password email, i am using mongodb to store these data my schema looks like:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
 var User = new Schema(
  {
    username: {type: String, required: true,unique: true },
    password: {type: String,required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    admin: { type: Boolean, default: false }},
  { usePushEach: true},
  {timestamps: true }
);    
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

i have a middleware before hitting the endpoint with the following code:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./models/user');

exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

i have an end point to hit signup and i have written this :

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
  Users.register(
 new Users({ username: req.body.username,email:req.body.email }),
 req.body.password,

 function(err, account) {
   if (err) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json({ err: "err" });
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        res.send("/books");
      })})});
```

when i pass the json object with username password email after the changes i got this error in postman

```
{
    "err": {
        "errors": {
            "password": {
                "message": "Path `password` is required.",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `password` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "password"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "password",
                "$isValidatorError": true
            }
        },
        "_message": "User validation failed",
        "message": "User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

can anyone help me in this whether i am having issue with npm package or is there any call back i have to handle,I cant figure out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to define the password in your schema. Passport-local-mongoose will take care of that for you!

"You're free to define your User how you like. Passport-Local Mongoose will add a username, hash and salt field to store the username, the hashed password and the salt value." - https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose

Try this instead:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
 var User = new Schema(
  {
    username: {type: String, required: true,unique: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    admin: { type: Boolean, default: false }},
  { usePushEach: true},
  {timestamps: true }
);    
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  Users.register(
    new Users({ username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email}),
    req.body.password,
    function(err, account) {
      if (err) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({ err: 'err' });
      }
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
        res.send('/books');
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply , i have tried that and got this error :(node:16132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Pass phrase must be a buffer    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:702:20)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2 (crypto.js:682:10)    at pbkdf2 (D:\reactLibrary\server\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\lib\pbkdf2.js:8:12)

Comment: This is interesting. Did you check to see if the req.body.password exists?

Comment: This is strange because you're trying to create a new user on the third line, but you can't without including the password in your document as well (per the schema definition). The error that you got when you ran my code is saying that you need to convert your password to a buffer for it to be valid.

Comment: Okay so I'm looking through the documentation, and it looks like you don't want to define the password field in your schema; passport-local-mongoose takes care of that for you. Will update my answer and that should solve your problem

Comment: Yup! See the new code above. Passport-local-mongoose takes care of that for you.

Here are the docs for reference - https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose

Comment: I hope that did the trick. If that solved your issue, please upvote my answer when you have the chance!